# Is it possible to put application.yml variables in to property file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

my spring boot project using the application.yml as the configuration, and I don't want to write the DB credentials in it, as the yml file is part of the source code which will be pushed into a public code repository. So I need to put the credentials into the properites file and the put the properties file somewhere on the application host server.

So, is it possbile to externalize the expression within  application.yml into a property file?

e.g. 
sprint boot application with the the application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    jdbc-url: ${url}
    username: ${user}
    password: ${pwd}
```

then we can put the credentials into app.properties as below, and put this file into the the host server.

```
url="jdbc:xxxx"
user="username"
pwd="password"
```

Comment: Smells like an XY problem to me. What are you trying to solve?

Comment: @BoristheSpider updated the description a bit.

Comment: Okay, What's wrong with envrionment variables? Or actually [_installing_](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html) your Spring Boot project correctly on the application server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very common concerns among all developers, how to secure database credentials in order to prevent any misuse, but trust me keeping credential in separate file won't add much value to situation.

If someone is capable of accessing you application.yml then once can also access you property file residing in separate folder.

> > Having understood your problem, that you need to push your code in public repository, you must protect what is yours. I have few inputs.
>
> - you don't need separate property file and respective variable in your application.yml, you can provide your values and you can always
>     override them outside your application during application start up.

for Example

```
spring:
  datasource:
    jdbc-url: myFakeURL
    username: MyFakeUserName
    password: myFakePAssword
```

once you have defined them, you can override them like

```
java -jar -Dspring.datasource.jdbc-url=myRealURL  -Dspring.datasource.jdbc-username=myRealUserName  -Dspring.datasource.password=myRealpassword   myApplication.jar
```

**Remember: this is one way, there are another ways too**

You can create you shell script/batch file (containing these property) and execute then before starting your application

> With spring boot there are few things which you *MUST* consider doing
>   i.e. **encrypting your property values**. Spring has beautiful support
>   with [Jasypt](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-jasypt) for encrypted properties and trust me you will have
>   to almost **no effort**

**you can also explore [Managing Secrets with Vault](https://spring.io/blog/2016/06/24/managing-secrets-with-vault)**

Comment: yeah, using shell scripts is a way out.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by calling the file `application.properties`.

But keep in mind the properties names should be similar to the yaml structure:

```
spring.datasource.url="jdbc:xxxx"
spring.datasource.user="username"
spring.datasource.pwd="password"
```

Comment: question asks to define properties in separate file and use them in application.yml

Comment: Can I reach .yml file via application.properties ? I have application which uses bootstrap.yml, busdriver.yml and  busdriverdev.yml. I have changed bootstrap.yml into application.properties but I need to reach busdriver.yml. How can do that ?